# How to get the row count of update,insert,delete query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I have a postgresql tables. user may update records or delete records manually using interface or using query. I need to track how many records have been updated ,deleted into a log table.I had tried as below update operations count can be tracked successfully. But delete operations count are not logging to log table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edmonton.count_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
v_old_data TEXT;
v_new_data TEXT;
log_count INTEGER;
BEGIN


IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
log_count = count(row(new));
RAISE NOTICE 'update operations';
INSERT INTO edmonton.log ("timestamp",message,type,project_area,count)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'records updated in Builder 
table','Information','edmonton',log_count);
RETURN NEW;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
v_old_data := ROW(OLD.*);
log_count = count(row(old));
RAISE NOTICE 'delete operations';
INSERT INTO edmonton.log ("timestamp",message,type,project_area,count)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'records deleted in Builder 
table','Information','edmonton',log_count);
RETURN OLD;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
v_new_data := ROW(NEW.*);
log_count = count(row(new));
RAISE NOTICE 'insert operations';
INSERT INTO edmonton.log ("timestamp",message,type,project_area,count)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'records inserted in Builder 
table','Information','edmonton',log_count);
RETURN NEW;
ELSE
RAISE WARNING '[EDMONTON.COUNT_FUNC] - Other action occurred: %, at 
%',TG_OP,now();
RETURN NULL;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN data_exception THEN
RAISE WARNING '[EDMONTON.COUNT_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [DATA EXCEPTION] - 
SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
RETURN NULL;
WHEN unique_violation THEN
RAISE WARNING '[EDMONTON.COUNT_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [UNIQUE] - SQLSTATE: %, 
SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
RETURN NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE WARNING '[EDMONTON.COUNT_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: %, 
SQLERRM: %',SQLSTATE,SQLERRM;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = pg_catalog, edmonton;
```

And this is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER count_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON edmonton.builder
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE edmonton.count_func();
```

I am getting a warning message when updating a record and messages were not logged to log table.

```
WARNING:  [EDMONTON.COUNT_FUNC] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: 55000, SQLERRM: record "old" is not assigned yet
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function count_func() line 49 at RAISE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not able to count inserted/updated/deleted rows that way. The expression

```
count(row(new))
```

always returns 1 as `row(new)` is a single row.

Second, the records `new` and `old` are not set in a trigger for each statement. Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> NEW
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is unassigned in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.

Comment: So statement level trigger can't be implemented?

Comment: Of course it can, but what value do you expect to be assigned to `new` when the trigger is executed only once for multiple rows?

Comment: Is there any way to log the count for each operation using statement level triggers?

Comment: It's possible with two triggers, one for each row before ins/upd/del and another for each statement after ins/upd/del. Using diagnostics is a simpler, more natural way.

Comment: Can you please share some snippets?

Comment: If i do two separate update statements like below,there are two records being created in statements_log table with count as 1 in 1 record and count as 2 in another record.Is it not possible to create a single record with count '2'?update edmonton.builder 
set source_builder = 'test' 
where source_builder = 'test1';
update edmonton.builder 
set source_builder = 'IH1' 
where source_builder = 'IH123';

Comment: If you want the solution to work for multiple inserts in a single transaction you should add a unique constraint in `statements_log`. [See the modified example.](http://rextester.com/UOU25781) However, I have to say I do not like the idea. I would rather search an alternative solution without triggers.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

> NEW
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for
>   INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
>   **unassigned in statement-level triggers** and for DELETE operations.
>
> OLD
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for
>   UPDATE/DELETE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
>   **unassigned in statement-level triggers** and for INSERT operations.

So the real question is

> how does update/insert work?..

Comment: It can. But NEW and OLD are not assigned for it you can't refer to them

Comment: I dont think so. As I proposed already - use get diagnostics in plpgsql and returning +cte for sql

Comment: sure. no worries. don't forget to upvote/accept any/both answers if they helped